# iOS MKMapView didSelectAnnotationView called when moving touch

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I just realized that if you tap an Annotation view on a MKMapView and then move the finger around, didSelectAnnotationView gets called for every Annotation that is on the path of the finger movement.
Does didSelectAnnotationView react to any touch event? I always thought it would be touch down only, but this seems to be not the case.

So if you open some detailview on the callback method when clicking an Annotation and set back the selected state via deselectAnnotation:animated:, moving the finger around opens up multiple detailviews for the same Annotation.

Is this the wanted behaviour of an iOS Map?
Does anyone have similar experiences?
Or could it be a flaw in our implementation?

Is there any possiblity to cancel the touch event after the callback method was called?
I tried resignFirstResponder on both the MapView and the AnnotationView, did nothing.

Help much appreciated!

Regards
Kim

Comment: any solution, facing the same issue

Comment: Do you have deselectAnnotation called in your didSelect method?